# Java Comparing Objects

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create a binary search program that can use various types of variable(ints, floats, Strings, etc.) to see if an element exists in an array. I am trying to figure out how to compare the variables. Here's a sketch of what I am working with:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class BinarySearch{
//Receives the list as the first argument, and the number to search
// for as the second argument.
public static boolean binarySearch(Object list[], Object target) {
    int listLen = list.length;
    int min = 0;
    int max = list.length - 1;
    //execute the binary search
    while (true) {
        int guess = (min + max / 2);
        if(target.equals(list[guess])) return true;

        if(list < target) {       //What to do here?
            //do some stuff

        ...
```

I am not even sure if using an Object is the best method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `Object`, you need to use generic class or method - in my examples, I use the second one, since your method is static:

```
public class BinarySearch
{
    public static <T> boolean Run(T[] list, T target)
    {
    }
}
```

If you need to compare values, you may use [`Comparable<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface and [`compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) method, which

> Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns **a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer** as this object **is less than, equal to, or greater than** the specified object.

Let's make `T` extend `Comparable<T>`, and use `compareTo` method:

```
public class BinarySearch
{
  public static <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean Run(T[] list, T target)
  {
    int listLen = list.length;
    int min = 0;
    int max = list.length - 1;

    while (true) {
        int guess = (min + max / 2);
        if (target.equals(list[guess])) return true;

        if (list[guess].compareTo(target) < 0) { 
            // list[guess] is less than target
        } else {
            // list[guess] is larget than target
        }
    }
}
```

As most of Java classes extend `Comparable`, now, you are able to do:

```
Integer[] ints = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 25, 30, 50, 100 };
System.out.println(BinarySearch.Run(ints, 25));
// recognized as: System.out.println(BinarySearch.<Integer>Run(ints, 25));

String[] strings = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
System.out.println(BinarySearch.Run(strings, "c"));
// recognized as: System.out.println(BinarySearch.<String>Run(strings, "c"));
```

You can also use any custom class in your `BinarySearch` if it extends `Comparable<>` interface.

Comment: Looks like with some tweaking of my code this will do it. I'll have to look more into using generics.

Answer (score 0):

Use generic types for your input parameters, also have the input parameters include a Comparator so that the user can fully control how to compare whatever kinds of inputs are passed in.

The signature would look like

```
public static <T> int binarySearch(
    T[] list, T target, java.util.Comparator<? super T> comparator)
```

This is better than having the objects implement Comparable because objects may have to be sorted in different ways in different situations. If you use Comparable then you're stuck with only the way implemented by the things you're comparing, but with a search that uses Comparable you can pass in a different comparator for each different way your input list is sorted.

Your comparison becomes

```
int compareResult = comparator.compare(target, list[guess]);
```

where a result of 0 means the 2 objects are equal, a negative result means the first argument is less than the second argument, and a positive result means the first argument is greater than the second argument.

Check how you calculate the midpoint, the code you have is broken due to how operator precedence works. Also you can run into problems for big arrays (greater than half of Integer.MAX_VALUE) if you're not careful.

Answer (score 0):

We can use Collections.binarySearch(...) method from java collections api, unless I am missing something.

Comment: The binary search is more of an exercise for me. Glad to know that's there if I need it.